# How to stop a foreach loop at a certain count

Tags: php, foreach

I am trying to stop a foreach loop and a child foreach loop at a combined count of 8 but its not currently working and ends up echoing 15 times .heres the code I currently have

```
    $i=0;
    foreach($somethings as $something){
    if (++$i == 8) break;
    echo something;
           foreach($subsomethings as $subsomething){
           if (++$i == 8) break;
           echo $subsomething
           }    
   }
```

how do I close both foreach loops if `$i == 8` 
Thanks

Comment: `if (++$i == 8) break 2;` in the second loop

Comment: just checking - do you want to use another variable in inner loop?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `++$i >= 8` instead of `++$i == 8`.  When the inner loop is broken the outer loop continues as $i is incremented to 9.

Answer (score 0):

Change the first if to be greater than or equal to:

```php
if (++$i >= 8) break;
```